# Can't understand why $broadcast isn't working

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have a module called 'mainApp'. In my 'mainApp' I have that 'MainCtrl' created and the service of 'appState' injected on it. It's used to persist some global informations that will be used in other module and many controllers.

In my 'myApp' module, I declared another module as dependency, one I called 'keyboardShortcuts', where I created a directive to control keyboard events.

```
angular.module "mainApp"
  .controller "MainCtrl", ['$rootScope','$scope','mensagemFactory','appState',($rootScope,$scope,mensagemFactory,appState) ->

    $rootScope.$watch () ->
      appState.getPointer 'actualScreenState'
    , (newValue, oldValue) ->
      console.log 'got here'
      $rootScope.$broadcast 'screenState.changed'
      undefined

    $scope.consoleProcessos = () ->
      mensagemFactory.getMensagens()
        .then (data) ->
          console.log 'processos: ' , data
        ,(error) ->
          console.log 'erro: ', error

    $scope.title = appState.getProp 'actualScreenState','title'

    $rootScope.$on 'screenState.changed' , ->
      $scope.title = appState.getProp 'actualScreenState','title'

    $rootScope.$on 'keyboardShortcut.undo' , () ->
      appState.undo 'actualScreenState'
    $rootScope.$on 'keyboardShortcut.redo' , () ->
      appState.redo 'actualScreenState'

    undefined
  ]
```

here follows my appState code

```
angular.module "mainApp"
  .factory "appState" , [() ->
    return new AppState()
  ]

cloneObject = (obj) ->
  if obj is null or typeof obj isnt 'object'
    return obj
  temp = obj.constructor()
  for key of obj
    temp[key] = cloneObject obj[key]
  return temp

class AppState

  storage = {
    actualScreenState: [{
      subject: 'AtosSuite'
    }]
  }

  pointers = {
    actualScreenState:0
  }

  historyStorage = {

  }

  window.storager = storage
  window.pointers = pointers

  getPointer: (collection)->
    return pointers[collection]

  undo: (collection) ->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined and pointers[collection] isnt undefined
      if pointers[collection] > 0
        pointers[collection] -= 1
        return true
      return false
    else
      return false

  redo: (collection) ->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined and pointers[collection] isnt undefined
      if pointers[collection] - 1 <= storage[collection].length
        pointers[collection] += 1
        return true
      else
        return false
    else
      return false

  getCollect: (collection) ->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined
      pointer = pointers[collection] or 0
      return storage[collection][pointer]
    else
      return false

  setNewCollect: (collection) ->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined
      return false
    else
      pointers[collection] = 0
      storage[collection] = {}
      return true

  getProp: (collection,prop)->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined
      pointer = pointers[collection] || 0
      return storage[collection][pointer][prop]
    else
      return false

  setProp: (collection,properties,values)->
    if storage[collection] isnt undefined
      if pointers[collection] is undefined
        pointers[collection] = storage[collection].length-1
      pointer = pointers[collection] || 0
      storage[collection] = storage[collection].slice 0,pointer+1
      tempObject = cloneObject storage[collection][pointer]
      if typeof properties is 'object'
        for property,index in properties
          tempObject[property] = values[index]
      else
        tempObject[properties] = values
      storage[collection].push tempObject
      pointers[collection] += 1
      return true
    else
      return false
```

My directive to control keyboard events follows:

```
angular.module "keyboardShortcuts"
  .directive 'globalDirective' , ['$rootScope','$document','$log',($rootScope,$document,$log) ->
    {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: () ->

        $document.bind 'keypress' , (event) ->
          if event.keyCode is 26
            $rootScope.$broadcast 'keyboardShortcut.undo'
          if event.keyCode is 25
            $rootScope.$broadcast 'keyboardShortcut.redo'
    }
  ]
```

Here is a controller I use my service too:

```
angular.module "mainApp"
  .controller "screenState", ['$rootScope','$scope','appState',($rootScope,$scope,appState) ->

    $scope.possibleStates = [
      'page1',
      'page2',
      'page3',
      'page4'
    ]

    $scope.actualState = 0

    appState.setProp 'actualScreenState' , ['possibleStates','actualState'] , [$scope.possibleStates,0]

    $scope.changeState = (newIndex) ->
      $scope.actualState = newIndex
      appState.setProp 'actualScreenState' , ['actualState','title'] , [$scope.actualState,(appState.getProp 'actualScreenState', 'possibleStates')[$scope.actualState]]
      undefined

    undefined

  ]
```

The problem is: When I use the 'changeState' method of the 'screenState' controller, my $watched object is changed, it $broadcast my event which is received many others controllers. BUT, when I trigger my keyboard event, its received by my directive, which changes my $watched object BUT my $watch function doesnt get it. I can check in my console the object changing, but somehow my $watch event is not triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: my mistake, the problem, I think, is on the $watch function. Somehow it's not detecting the object change.

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` is only able to determine if watched values have changed during the digest cycle, which your keypress event listener does not cause.

A simple solution would be to call `$rootScope.$digest();` at the end of your keypress event listener. However, this would cause performance issues as your application grows.

Comment: Thanks man! It's good to know! I changed my code. As my app is growing, I thought it would be better if I discard this pointer idea and work with other history collection.

But thanks, I'll test it later to understand it in practice.

Comment: Nice! I called $digest at the end of undo event. It works and I think it's not gonna be a scalability problem. what you think?

Comment: The issue with it is, it's going to check every watched expression for changes (the digest procedure) basically every time a keypress event is fired (unless a listener stops propagation before the delegate listener is invoked), which can be an extremely frequent occurrence, especially when form inputs are frequent, or users require keyboard navigation for accessibility reasons.

Frequent digests + many watchers can be a bit of an issue, so usually you want to try to minimize how much of this you're doing (eg, only digest if you decide the right combination of keys are pressed)

Comment: yep, I got it. So I decided to go not for the keypress event, but for my personal event, which is triggered by some combination of keys pressing. When they get pressed, I trigger my event and then I invoke the $digest. I think it could minify this problem, right?